# Simple Random Walk & Irreducibility

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I know that simple random walk (SRW) on a connected graph is irreducible. I understand why based on intuition and logic, but I'm having a hard time convincing myself mathematically. Is there a rigorous proof for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with the definition of two nodes communicating --i.e. non-zero probability of transitioning from some node $i$ to some node $j$ in finitely many states.  For $i\lt j$, $k:= j-i$ and by inspection the probability of going from $i\to j$ in k steps is $2^{-k}$. By symmetry that is also the probability of going from $j\to i$ in exactly $k$ steps. A lot of this comes down to looking up and directly applying definitions.

Comment: Why is the probability of going from i to j in k steps 2^-k? Where is the 2 coming from? (are we assuming degree equals 2 for each node?)

Comment: Based on your questions, the main issue right now is you need to provide a definition of the simple random walk. You ask “are we assuming degree equals 2 for each node”— well that’s the standard definition of simple random walk.  See eg here: http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/Lecture16.pdf ... there are obvious generalizations to unfair coins but fundamentally this is a walk generated by coin tossing.  Really you need to clearly state the definition you are using especially if it’s nonstandard. If you accept coin tossing as the generator, $2^{-k}$ should be clear